# Crop a section of a PDF page using FPDI

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdi

I am using FPDI-TCPDF to insert an already existing PDF to a PDF created by using TCPDF. Can I crop a section of already existing Page before inserting into the new PDF?

I am using below code which insert the entire page (page number 2). But I want only a small section from this page to be inserted. Is there any way to do this?

```
$pdf->AddPage('L');
$pdf->setSourceFile('samplepdf.pdf');
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(2);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 270, 200);
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
```